# How to simplify a for loop to get each value in Django.(See Description)?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a class which i call from views.py

```
class getData(set):
    def __init__(self,itemList):

        super(getData,self).__init__((Data(item) for item in itemList))
```

which calls another class "Data"where happens the database query for each item.
I want to add exception handling such that i can create a list of items for which database does not hold any record.

I tried :

```
try:
    for item in itemList:
        super(getData,self).__init__(Data(item))
except:
      print item
      raise valueError, item not available.
```

Can anyone please help me to achieve this.

Edit:
An item is a name of a sample for which there is a whole lot of calculations are done and for each sample there is a tree generated and for that for each item a separate query is done.

Comment: Couldn't you just run a single query to determine which items are not in the database? Please tell us a bit more on your setup. What are the `item` objects, what does `Data` constructor do, and so on.

Comment: Added in the question.Please let me know if i need to add something more.

Comment: @AlexMorozov Can you help me simplify the loop and make "item" accessible

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inheriting from the `set` I'd implemented it like that:

```
class GetData(object):
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.absent = set()
        for item in items:  
            try:
                # Make a query and raise an exception if there's no such object
                Data(item)
            except DoesNotExist:
                self.absent.update(item)    
        # do something with the self.absent list
```

Comment: Thank you so much Alex for the help.I will try to implement this .

Comment: Well, it contains the list of the items which caused the exception, that is, the items not in your database. It's a `set`, so you can iterate it, convert in to list, etc.